# Merging two pandas dataframes with date variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to merger two `pandas dataframes` based on common `date` variable. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.to_datetime(['2010-12-31', '2012-12-31']), 'val' : [1,2]})
datarange = pd.DataFrame(pd.period_range('2009-12-31', '2012-12-31', freq='A'), columns = ['date'])
pd.merge(datarange, data, how = 'left', on = 'date')
```

With this I get below result

```
   date  val
0  2009  NaN
1  2010  NaN
2  2011  NaN
3  2012  NaN
```

Could you please help how can I correctly merge these two `dataframes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `right_on` for same anual periods like in `datarange['date']` column:

```
df = pd.merge(datarange, 
              data, 
              how = 'left',
              left_on = 'date', 
              right_on=data['date'].dt.to_period('A'))
print (df)
   date date_x     date_y  val
0  2009   2009        NaT  NaN
1  2010   2010 2010-12-31  1.0
2  2011   2011        NaT  NaN
3  2012   2012 2012-12-31  2.0
```

Or create helper column:

```
df = pd.merge(datarange, 
              data.assign(datetimes=data['date'], date=data['date'].dt.to_period('A')), 
              how = 'left',
              on = 'date')
print (df)
   date  val  datetimes
0  2009  NaN        NaT
1  2010  1.0 2010-12-31
2  2011  NaN        NaT
3  2012  2.0 2012-12-31
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is it possible to obtain final result in the form of `2010-12-31` instead `2010` i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Comment: @BrianSmith - do you think `df['date'] = df['date'].dt.to_timestamp('A').dt.normalize()` after second solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge on a common type.

For example you can set the year as merging key on each side:

```
pd.merge(datarange, data, how='left',
         left_on=datarange['date'].dt.year,
         right_on=data['date'].dt.year
        )
```

output:

```
   key_0 date_x     date_y  val
0   2009   2009        NaT  NaN
1   2010   2010 2010-12-31  1.0
2   2011   2011        NaT  NaN
3   2012   2012 2012-12-31  2.0
```